# how to implement caffe deconvolution padding in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

This layer has pad 4 pixel of each side but in tensorflow it just has "SAME" and "VALID" padding mode. How to implement this layer in tensorflow ?

```
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "conv26"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0.1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 1
    kernel_size: 9
    stride: 3
    pad: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.001
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.pad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) for custom padding. To pad a tensor named `my_tensor` with shape `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` with four zeros on both sides for each spatial dimension:

```
my_padded_tensor = tf.pad(
    tensor=my_tensor,
    paddings=tf.constant([[0, 0,], [4, 4], [4,4], [0,0]], dtype=tf.int32),
    mode='CONSTANT',
    constant_values=0
)
```

Comment: I have used tf.pad to pad input before  tf.nn.conv2d_transpose but the output not follow the deconvolution fomula output_size = strides * (input_size-1) + kernel_size - 2*padding for example if I have input_size = 6 , strides = 4 , kernel_size = 9 , padding=2 the output should be 21 but the output is 61.